# CWnd::GetParent causes an exception

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog, cwnd

I am trying to call the function GetParent() of CWnd class.
Every time there is an exception thrown. 
I'm calling the function from a working thread.

This is the line that causes the exception:
CWnd* parent = this->GetParent();

I've also tried "GetParent()->PostMessage(........);", and still the exception is thrown.

I'm using this method in a CDialog.

I have noticed that the CWnd member m_hWnd is sometimes 0x00000000 or 0x00000001.
In a different computer I don't get this exception. 
Is it a problem in the project settings or in my code?

Comment: Post the relevant code (5-6 lines of code around the line with the error)

Comment: As CDialog derives from CWnd, it must have a member named m_hWnd, check in a debugger if the value is != 0.

Comment: You say "from a working thread."  Does this mean that you have created this CWnd class on a thread started by AfxBeginThread, and if so have you [followed msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b807sta6(v=vs.100).aspx) for overriding the InitInstance function?   Since this works on a different computer, and as @neagoegab points out your m_hWnd is not a valid window, you may be dealing with a race condition where the GetParent() is being called before the CWnd is created and initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You receive an assertion and not an exception.

Here is the implementation from VS 2010:

```
ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return CWnd::FromHandle(::GetParent(m_hWnd));
```

Your m_hWnd is not a window...